# button has to perform slightly different action depending on placement

Tags: java, javafx

**Situation:** I'm writing a simple note-taking program from scratch for a school project using java and JavaFX. I'm using tags to group notes. I can add tags to a note and if it's a new tag that is created it is also added to my tag-cloud.

Each tag has a button marked with an X. I now need to make the button work but depending on the placement of the tag I need it to do one of two things:
1) if the user wishes to remove a tag from a note I need to remove the tag from the tagbar (which is a TilePane) where the tags of that specific note are shown and remove it from the note.
2) if the user wishes to delete the tag altogether the user clicks X of the tag in the tag-cloud (which is a FlowPane) and the tag is then removed from the tag-cloud and from all notes.

**Problem:** As far as I understand it I need to make two different actions for the same button and I have no idea how to make that work.

**Ideas:** I have thought of making two different kinds of tags each with its own FXML-file but I'm not sure.

**Question:** How do I make two different actions for the same button and how do I make it so that the right action is called?

**Here's a link to what the program looks like so far:**
[image]

Comment: I see 2 different `x` buttons. One on the top ("cloud") and one on the left. Assign each its own action.

Comment: To know where the button is located all you have to do is make sure the parent that holds the buttons have an fx:id. Then when you click the button see who the parent is. Switch the action on parent.

Comment: These aren't the same buttons though. E.g. the "private" tag button in the tag bar is (necessarily) a different button to the "private" tag button in the tag cloud. So each one has an event handler which performs a different action. Where is the problem?

Comment: A nice post about tags [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378973/implement-tags-bar-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an app you can play with. I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378973/implement-tags-bar-in-javafx) for the start. This app creates two sets of tags and deletes all tags with the same id if one is deleted.

> Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication102 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }        
}
```

> Controller:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private VBox vbMain;

    @FXML 
    private FlowPane fpMain;

    String[] tagType = {"Chicken", "Soup", "Fall", "Winter", "Happy"};
    Random random = new Random();




    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        int control = random.nextInt(5);

        HBox tag1 = new HBox();
        tag1.setId(tagType[control]);
        tag1.setStyle("-fx-padding:4;" +
            "        -fx-border-width: 2;" +
            "        -fx-border-color: black;" +
            "        -fx-border-radius: 4;" +
            "        -fx-background-color: f1f1f1;" +
            "        -fx-border-insets: 5;");
        tag1.setSpacing(5);
        tag1.setPrefHeight(20);
        tag1.setMaxWidth(75);

        tag1.getChildren().add(new Label(tagType[control]));

        Label closingX1 = new Label("x");
        tag1.getChildren().add(closingX1);         
        closingX1.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event1) -> {
            System.out.println("Parent: " + ((Label) event1.getSource()).getParent().getParent());      
            for(Node child : fpMain.getChildren())
            {
                if(child.getId().equals(tag1.getId()))
                {
                    Platform.runLater(()->fpMain.getChildren().remove(child));
                }
            }

            for(Node child : vbMain.getChildren())
            {
                if(child.getId().equals(tag1.getId()))
                {
                    Platform.runLater(()->vbMain.getChildren().remove(child));
                }
            }            
        });


        vbMain.getChildren().add(tag1);



        HBox tag2 = new HBox(); 
        tag2.setId(tagType[control]);
        tag2.setStyle("-fx-padding:4;" +
            "        -fx-border-width: 2;" +
            "        -fx-border-color: black;" +
            "        -fx-border-radius: 4;" +
            "        -fx-background-color: f1f1f1;" +
            "        -fx-border-insets: 5;");
        tag2.setSpacing(5);
        tag2.setPrefHeight(20);
        tag2.setMaxWidth(75);        
        tag2.getChildren().add(new Label(tagType[control]));

        Label closingX2 = new Label("x");
        tag2.getChildren().add(closingX2);          
        closingX2.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event1) -> {
            System.out.println("Parent: " + ((Label) event1.getSource()).getParent().getParent());   
            for(Node child : vbMain.getChildren())
            {
                if(child.getId().equals(tag2.getId()))
                {
                    Platform.runLater(()->vbMain.getChildren().remove(child));
                }
            }

            for(Node child : fpMain.getChildren())
            {
                if(child.getId().equals(tag2.getId()))
                {
                    Platform.runLater(()->fpMain.getChildren().remove(child));
                }
            }  
        });

        fpMain.getChildren().add(tag2);        
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {    

    }    

}
```

> FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="623.0" prefWidth="820.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication102.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="372.0" layoutY="569.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="add button" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <VBox fx:id="vbMain" prefHeight="549.0" prefWidth="387.0" />
      <FlowPane fx:id="fpMain" layoutX="371.0" layoutY="18.0" prefHeight="505.0" prefWidth="434.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

In the pictures below, I added three tags randomly and then deleted the chicken tag.

[image][image]