# How should i implement delete functionality in monthView calendar

Tags: java, javafx, calendar

## How it's begin

Hi first time here and a amateur dev.
I'm developing a calendar like a Google month view calendar with JavaFX
using `ObservableArrayList` as a structure to cache events from database and lay them down into a `GridPane` cell. Similar to Google's, each day can hold multiple events. Structure is something like this

```
GridPane contains Vbox which contains multiple event labels.
```

## The problem

The label calls `EventBox`don't know what index of event is so i can't use `remove(int index)` to remove the associate event from `ObservableList` so how should i implement this delete functionality?

Some curiousity: is `ObservableList` good for this kind of thing?

## My current solution

I think mark event as cancelled, delete the event from database and update the whole screen by calling `updateView`. The event is still in a list but it won't show up anymore.

Some code:

```
private void updateView() {
    // ...set month and year text

    // layout detail of all cells
    LocalDate firstDateOfMonth = currentMonth.withDayOfMonth(1);
    int firstDayOfWeek = firstDateOfMonth.getDayOfWeek().getValue() % 7;
    int indexDay = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView.getRowConstraints().size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridView.getColumnConstraints().size(); j++) {
            DateCell cell = gridCells[i][j];
            LocalDate currentDate = firstDateOfMonth.plusDays(indexDay - firstDayOfWeek);
            cell.getChildren().clear();
            cell.setDate(currentDate);
            setCellDetail(cell);
            indexDay++;
        }
    }

}

private void setCellDetail(DateCell cell) {
    // ... setup date header

    // main loop to lay events
    for (Event event : eventList.getEvents()) {
        if (cell.getDate().equals(event.getStart()) && cell.getChildren().size() < 4) {
            EventBox eventBox = createEventBox(event);
            cell.getChildren().add(eventBox);
        }
    }
}
```

program is something like this:
[PROGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmzJ8.png)

Comment: I would say make your `Label` a custom tag. A `Tag` object can be an `HBox` with a `Label` and a `Button`. The `Label` holds the info and the `Button` has an `x` as it's display text. Use the `Button`'s `onAction` to get it to delete itself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378973/implement-tags-bar-in-javafx) are some `Tag` ideas but they are overkill for what you need. You only need the basics mentioned above.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sedj601/CalendarFx) is one I started on. It uses [`SQLite`](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/), [`ControlsFx`](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/), and [`FxIconics`](https://github.com/pepperonas/FxIconics). Add these three `Jars` to the project and it's a go. You have to go to March 2017 to see the one tag that can be deleted. I started this but never finished.

Comment: Thanks for awesome API. It will come in handy.