# How do I create a textbox JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, textfield

I am writing a tableview based program which stores its values in MySQL. 
I need to create textBoxes with x button like in Gmail in textfields class(considering that there would be several boxes in one field) with auto completion on JavaFX. The Boxes supposed to be like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y58HM.png)

The box also will have hidden values, supposed to be stored in MySQL and do some action when clicked on them.

Apologize if question is simple I am kind of beginner in Java

Comment: There are many tutorials on JavaFX, for example [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/text-field.htm), did you check any?

Comment: I think you should look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378973/implement-tags-bar-in-javafx

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378973/implement-tags-bar-in-javafx

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the button in the TextBox:

```
CustomTextField textfield = new CustomTextField
textfield.setRight(new Button());
```

And on button you can add every style what you want