# MySQL javafx search like

Tags: mysql, javafx, sql-like

I'm losing my mind over this. Maybe its something very simple that I miss. But I can't seem to get it work. I received help from other users and edited my code. But really can't get it to work.

This is my table in my database

```
+----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|  colID         | colTitle              | colKeywords         |
+----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 1              |  Jumanji              | comedy adventure    |
| 2              |  Moana                | adventure animation |
| 3              |  Shawshank Redemption | drama tearjerker    |
| 4              |  Avengers             | action              |
+----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+

        +-----------------------------+    +---------+    
Search: | adventure and action movies |    |button GO|
        +-----------------------------+    +---------+
```

What I want to do is if I type "adventure and action movies" in the textfield, and after I hit the button go, the result in the tableview should be:

```
Jumanji
Moana
Avengers
```

My updated code:

```
public class UserMainPageController implements Initializable {



    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    @FXML
    private TableView table_title;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn titleCol;

    @FXML
    private TextField txt_search;




    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {




    }    



    @FXML
    private void logOut(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        Main.showUserLogin();

    }




    @FXML
    private void goSearch(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException{


       try{

        conn = SqlConnection.ConnectDB();
        String criteria = txt_search.getText();
        if (criteria.trim().length() == 0) { return; }
        String[] arryCriterion = criteria.split(" ");
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arryCriterion.length; i++) {

            List<String> text = populateField(arryCriterion[i], conn);

            results.addAll(text);

        }

        ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(results);

        table_title.setItems(observableList);


    }finally{
        conn.close();
    }
}   

    private List<String> populateField(String s, Connection conn) throws SQLException{

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_entry WHERE colTitle LIKE ? ";


    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, "%" + s + "%");
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        myList.add(rs.getString("colTitle"));
    }
    return myList;

    }


}
```

If I press the search button, nothing seems to appear in the tableview

Comment: This is so much easier to troubleshoot if you simply place a breakpoint and step through these codes.

Comment: Are you getting the SQL results or the problem is about putting those in your TableView?

Comment: I created a sample app that takes a different approach. If you haven't figured this out tomorrow and if I don't forget, I will post it.

Comment: Why not just filter the table directly in Java, instead of sending a new database request every time? See, for example, http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/

Comment: hi sedrick still havent figured it out.. is your approach involves the one with having separate Id's for each keyword? the many to many approach?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, my approach is similar to what @James_D is suggesting. First get all the data from the `Database`. Then filter the data using `Java`.

In my `Database`, I use Unicode Character `INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE (U+001D)` between each keyword. Example: `comedy↔adventure`. I do this so that I can get each keyword using `String.split()`.

In the app, I use a `FilteredList` to filter the `TableView`. If a DB(Database) entry contains at least one of the keywords, That entry will be shown. `!Collections.disjoint(Movie.KeywordsStringToList(t.getColKeywords()), searchingFor);` handles this.

Also, I have created a `Tag` class. This helps me keep up with things. These `Tags` look terrible, but you can beautify them using ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378973/implement-tags-bar-in-javafx).

**Code:**

> Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final TableView<Movie> table = new TableView<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550); 

        TableColumn colID = new TableColumn("ID");
        colID.setMinWidth(100);
        colID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("colID"));

        TableColumn colTitle = new TableColumn("Title");
        colTitle.setMinWidth(100);
        colTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("colTitle"));

        TableColumn colKeywords = new TableColumn("Keywords");
        colKeywords.setMinWidth(200);
        colKeywords.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("colKeywords"));

        DBHandler dbhandler = new DBHandler();
        FilteredList<Movie> filteredList = new FilteredList(dbhandler.getDBMovies());
        table.setItems(filteredList);
        table.getColumns().addAll(colID, colTitle, colKeywords);

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        TextField searchField = new TextField();
        searchField.setOnAction(event -> {
            List<String> searchingFor = new ArrayList();

            Tag tempTag = new Tag(searchField.getText());
            tempTag.getCloseButton().setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {
                flowPane.getChildren().remove(tempTag);
                if(flowPane.getChildren().isEmpty())
                {
                    filteredList.setPredicate(null);
                }
                else{
                    filteredList.setPredicate((t) -> {
                        return !Collections.disjoint(Movie.KeywordsStringToList(t.getColKeywords()), searchingFor);
                    });
                }
            });
            flowPane.getChildren().add(tempTag);

            for(Node node : flowPane.getChildren())
            {
                searchingFor.add(((Tag)node).getText());
            }
            filteredList.setPredicate((t) -> {
                return !Collections.disjoint(Movie.KeywordsStringToList(t.getColKeywords()), searchingFor);
            });

            searchField.clear();
        });

        HBox hbox = new HBox(searchField, flowPane);
        final VBox vbox = new VBox(table, hbox);
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

> Movie Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class Movie {
    private static final String INFORMATION_SEPARATOR_THREE = "\u001D";

    private final IntegerProperty colID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final StringProperty colTitle = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty colKeywords = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Movie(int colID, String colTitle, String colKeywords)
    {
        this.colID.set(colID);
        this.colTitle.set(colTitle);
        this.colKeywords.set(colKeywords);
    }


    public void setColID(int colID)
    {
        this.colID.set(colID);
    }

    public int getColID()
    {
        return this.colID.get();
    }

    public void setColTitle(String colTitle)
    {
        this.colTitle.set(colTitle);
    }

    public String getColTitle()
    {
        return this.colTitle.get();
    }

    public void setColID(String colKeywords)
    {
        this.colKeywords.set(colKeywords);
    }

    public String getColKeywords()
    {
        return this.colKeywords.get();
    }

    //Utility Methods
    //Converts a String of keywords to a list<String> of keywords
    public static List<String> KeywordsStringToList(String keywords)
    {
        String[] keywordsArray = keywords.split(INFORMATION_SEPARATOR_THREE);

        List<String> keywordsList = new ArrayList();
        for(String entry : keywordsArray)
        {
            keywordsList.add(entry);
        }

        return keywordsList;
    }

    //Convert a List<String> of keywords to a String of keywords
    public static String keywordsListToString(List<String> keywords)
    {
        return String.join(INFORMATION_SEPARATOR_THREE, keywords);
    }
}
```

> Database Handler Class: **This example uses an SQLite DB**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class DBHandler {
    Connection connection;

    public DBHandler()
    {
        try 
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:movie.db");
            System.out.println("connected to db!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DBHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    public ObservableList<Movie> getDBMovies()
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM MovieInfo";
        ObservableList<Movie> movies = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query))
        {
            while(result.next())
            {
                Movie movie = new Movie(result.getInt("id"), result.getString("title"), result.getString("keywords"));
                movies.add(movie);
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return movies;
    }

}
```

> Tag Class:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
final public class Tag extends HBox{
    final private Label keyword;
    final private Button closeButton;

    public Tag(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = new Label(keyword);
        closeButton = new Button("x");
        this.getChildren().addAll(this.keyword, closeButton);
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return keyword.getText();
    }

    Button getCloseButton()
    {
        return closeButton;
    }    
}
```

[image]

[Full Code including DB on GitHub](https://github.com/sedj601/JavaFXApplication48)