# JavaFx: Filter boxes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, controlsfx, jfoenix

I am implementing a filtering mechanism in JavaFx like an online shop's filter, so I can filter a table or a list of items by its properties using a filter pane where I have comboboxes/cehckboxes, sliders, etc. After I filter by on criteria,  I would like to add them in a row above the table in a boxes with their name and a cancel(x) button to remove it if the user want.

My question would be do you know if there is in any 3rd party library(I think by default in JavaFx there is no such item), I mean for example ControlFx, JFoenix or any other. If there is no, what would be the most elegant and easiest way to build one? I mean which pane/box/Node to use?

I would like something like:

[image]

or:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378973/implement-tags-bar-in-javafx

Comment: @Sedrick thanks, at the end I implemented something similar to that answer. i thought I can use something it is implemented instead of reinvent the wheel.