JavaFX tags not wrapping
Hey all I need some assistance in getting my tag app working as it should. Currently it displays values like this:

However, I am wanting it to wrap the tags instead of continuing to go horizontal. I changed all the HBox's to FlowPane's but that made it look all weird and didn't work well. I also tried doing VBox's but it still messes it up.
What I am wanting it to look like is this:

The current code:
package application;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

public class Main3 extends Application{
    Color txtColor;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         primaryStage.setTitle("TagInputFx Demo");

         VBox root = new VBox();
         AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox tagInput = new AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox();         
         ObservableSet<String> sug = FXCollections.observableSet();         
         String[] listOfDBCalls = "Integrated Security=, user=, password=, pwd=, Database=, Encrypt=, Trusted_Connection=, Persist Security Info=, TrustServerCertificate=, User ID=, Initial Catalog=, AttachDbFileName=, Failover Partner=, Asynchronous Processing=, User Instance=, Packet Size=, Column Encryption Setting=, Network Library=, MultipleActiveResultSets=, Data Source=, Server=, Enclave Attestation Url=, Provider=, UID=, Connect Timeout=, Driver=, MARS_Connection=, Proxy Password=, Proxy User Id=, Host=, Pooling=, Max Pool Size=, Connection Lifetime=, Incr Pool Size=, Decr Pool Size=, DBA Privilege=, Load Balancing=, Dbq=, DistribTX=, OledbKey1=, OledbKey2=, ConnectString=, Version=, New=, UseUTF16Encoding=, Legacy Format=, Read Only=, DateTimeFormat=, BinaryGUID=, Cache Size=, Page Size=, Enlist=, Max Page Count=, Journal Mode=, Synchronous=, Compress=, UTF8Encoding=, Timeout=, NoTXN=, SyncPragma=, StepAPI=, LongNames=, Port=, location=, sslmode=, Protocol=, SslMode=, MinPoolSize=, MaxPoolSize=".split(",");
         
         for (String call : listOfDBCalls) {
             sug.add(call);
         }         
         
         tagInput.setSuggestions(sug);
         tagInput.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);         
         
         Text header = new Text("Tags:");
         root.getChildren().addAll(header, tagInput);
         Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 250);
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();        
    }
    

    public static void main3(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    public class AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox extends HBox {
        private final ObservableList<String> tags;
        private final ObservableSet<String> suggestions;
        private ContextMenu entriesPopup;
        private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 15;
        private final TextField inputTextField;

        public AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox() {
            getStyleClass().setAll("tag-bar");
            getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            
            tags = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            suggestions = FXCollections.observableSet();
            inputTextField = new TextField();
            
            this.entriesPopup = new ContextMenu();
            
            setListner();
            
            inputTextField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) && !tags.isEmpty() && inputTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    String last = tags.get(tags.size() - 1);
                    String orgTag = last.split("=")[0] + "=";
                        
                    if (orgTag.length() > 2) {
                        suggestions.add(orgTag);
                        tags.remove(last);
                    }
                } else if (event.getCode().toString() == "ENTER" || event.getCode().toString() == "TAB" && !inputTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    String newTag = inputTextField.getText();
                    String orgTag = newTag.split("=")[0] + "=";

                    if (orgTag.length() > 2) {
                        suggestions.add(newTag);
                        tags.add(newTag);
                        inputTextField.setText("");
                        suggestions.remove(orgTag);
                        suggestions.remove(newTag);
                    }
                } else if (event.getCode().toString() == "ESCAPE") {
                    inputTextField.clear();
                } else if (event.getCode().toString() == "DOWN" || event.getCode().toString() == "UP") {
                    entriesPopup.getSkin().getNode().lookup(".menu-item").requestFocus();
                }
                
                System.out.println(event.getCode().toString());                    
            });

            inputTextField.prefHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());
            HBox.setHgrow(inputTextField, Priority.ALWAYS);
            inputTextField.setBackground(null);

            tags.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> change) -> {
                while (change.next()) {
                    if (change.wasPermutated()) {
                        ArrayList<Node> newSublist = new ArrayList<>(change.getTo() - change.getFrom());
                        
                        for (int i = change.getFrom(), end = change.getTo(); i < end; i++) {
                            newSublist.add(null);
                        }
                        
                        for (int i = change.getFrom(), end = change.getTo(); i < end; i++) {
                            newSublist.set(change.getPermutation(i), getChildren().get(i));
                        }
                        
                        getChildren().subList(change.getFrom(), change.getTo()).clear();
                        getChildren().addAll(change.getFrom(), newSublist);
                    } else {
                        if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                            getChildren().subList(change.getFrom(), change.getFrom() + change.getRemovedSize()).clear();
                        }
                        
                        if (change.wasAdded()) {
                            getChildren().addAll(change.getFrom(), change.getAddedSubList().stream().map(Tag::new).collect(
                                    Collectors.toList()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            
            getChildren().add(inputTextField);
        }

        private TextFlow buildTextFlow(String text, String filter) {
            int filterIndex = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase());
            Text textBefore = new Text(text.substring(0, filterIndex));
            Text textAfter = new Text(text.substring(filterIndex + filter.length()));
            Text textFilter = new Text(text.substring(filterIndex, filterIndex + filter.length()));
            
            textFilter.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
            textFilter.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
            
            return new TextFlow(textBefore, textFilter, textAfter);
        }

        private void setListner() {
            inputTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    entriesPopup.hide();
                } else {
                    List<String> filteredEntries = suggestions
                            .stream()
                            .filter(e -> e.toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                    if (!filteredEntries.isEmpty()) {
                        populatePopup(filteredEntries, newValue);
                        
                        if (!entriesPopup.isShowing()) {
                            entriesPopup.show(this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        entriesPopup.hide();
                    }
                }
            });

            focusedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> entriesPopup.hide());
        }

        private void populatePopup(List<String> searchResult, String searchRequest) {
            List<CustomMenuItem> menuItems = new LinkedList<>();
            
            searchResult.stream()
                    .limit(MAX_ENTRIES)
                    .forEach(result -> {
                        TextFlow textFlow = buildTextFlow(result, searchRequest);
                        textFlow.prefWidthProperty().bind(AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox.this.widthProperty());
                        CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(textFlow, true);
                        
                        menuItems.add(item);

                        item.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                            if (result.endsWith("=")) {
                                //Dont close it yet.. keep typing
                                inputTextField.setText(result);
                                inputTextField.requestFocus();
                                inputTextField.end();
                            } else {
                                //It has values on both sides of the =
                                //so lets add it to the tag list
                                tags.add(result);
                                suggestions.remove(result);
                                inputTextField.clear();
                                entriesPopup.hide();
                            }
                        });
                    });

            entriesPopup.getItems().clear();
            entriesPopup.getItems().addAll(menuItems);
        }

        public final ObservableList<String> getTags() {
            return tags;
        }

        public final ObservableSet<String> getSuggestions() {
            return suggestions;
        }
        
        public final void setTextColor(Color c) {
            txtColor = c;
        }

        public final void setSuggestions(ObservableSet<String> suggestions) {
            this.suggestions.clear();
            this.suggestions.addAll(suggestions);
        }

        private class Tag extends HBox {
            Tag(String tag) {
                Button removeButton = new Button();
                Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("delete.png").toExternalForm());
                ImageView view = new ImageView(img);
                
                view.setFitHeight(16);
                view.setPreserveRatio(true);
                
                getStyleClass().add("tag");
                
                removeButton.setBackground(null);
                removeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                    tags.remove(tag);
                    suggestions.add(tag);
                    inputTextField.requestFocus();
                });

                Text text = new Text(tag);
                
                text.setFill(txtColor);
                text.setFont(Font.font(text.getFont().getFamily(), FontWeight.BOLD, text.getFont().getSize()));

                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                setSpacing(2);
                setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5));

                removeButton.setGraphic(view);
                
                getChildren().addAll(text, removeButton);
            }
        }
    }
}

Is there a way of doing this with the hbox?
UPDATE 1
Using the code for the FlowPane this is what the output looks like:

The modified code to replace HBox with FlowPane:
package application;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

public class Main3 extends Application{
    Color txtColor;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         primaryStage.setTitle("TagInputFx Demo");

         VBox root = new VBox();
         AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox tagInput = new AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox();         
         ObservableSet<String> sug = FXCollections.observableSet();         
         String[] listOfDBCalls = "Integrated Security=, user=, password=, pwd=, Database=, Encrypt=, Trusted_Connection=, Persist Security Info=, TrustServerCertificate=, User ID=, Initial Catalog=, AttachDbFileName=, Failover Partner=, Asynchronous Processing=, User Instance=, Packet Size=, Column Encryption Setting=, Network Library=, MultipleActiveResultSets=, Data Source=, Server=, Enclave Attestation Url=, Provider=, UID=, Connect Timeout=, Driver=, MARS_Connection=, Proxy Password=, Proxy User Id=, Host=, Pooling=, Max Pool Size=, Connection Lifetime=, Incr Pool Size=, Decr Pool Size=, DBA Privilege=, Load Balancing=, Dbq=, DistribTX=, OledbKey1=, OledbKey2=, ConnectString=, Version=, New=, UseUTF16Encoding=, Legacy Format=, Read Only=, DateTimeFormat=, BinaryGUID=, Cache Size=, Page Size=, Enlist=, Max Page Count=, Journal Mode=, Synchronous=, Compress=, UTF8Encoding=, Timeout=, NoTXN=, SyncPragma=, StepAPI=, LongNames=, Port=, location=, sslmode=, Protocol=, SslMode=, MinPoolSize=, MaxPoolSize=".split(",");
         
         for (String call : listOfDBCalls) {
             sug.add(call);
         }         
         
         tagInput.setSuggestions(sug);
         tagInput.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);         
         
         Text header = new Text("Tags:");
         root.getChildren().addAll(header, tagInput);
         Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 250);
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();        
    }
    

    public static void main3(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    public class AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox extends FlowPane {
        private final ObservableList<String> tags;
        private final ObservableSet<String> suggestions;
        private ContextMenu entriesPopup;
        private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 15;
        private final TextField inputTextField;

        public AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox() {
            getStyleClass().setAll("tag-bar");
            getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            
            tags = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            suggestions = FXCollections.observableSet();
            inputTextField = new TextField();
            
            this.entriesPopup = new ContextMenu();
            
            setListner();
            
            inputTextField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) && !tags.isEmpty() && inputTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    String last = tags.get(tags.size() - 1);
                    String orgTag = last.split("=")[0] + "=";
                        
                    if (orgTag.length() > 2) {
                        suggestions.add(orgTag);
                        tags.remove(last);
                    }
                } else if (event.getCode().toString() == "ENTER" || event.getCode().toString() == "TAB" && !inputTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    String newTag = inputTextField.getText();
                    String orgTag = newTag.split("=")[0] + "=";

                    if (orgTag.length() > 2) {
                        suggestions.add(newTag);
                        tags.add(newTag);
                        inputTextField.setText("");
                        suggestions.remove(orgTag);
                        suggestions.remove(newTag);
                    }
                } else if (event.getCode().toString() == "ESCAPE") {
                    inputTextField.clear();
                } else if (event.getCode().toString() == "DOWN" || event.getCode().toString() == "UP") {
                    entriesPopup.getSkin().getNode().lookup(".menu-item").requestFocus();
                }
                
                System.out.println(event.getCode().toString());
                
                //inputTextField.clear();
                
            });

            inputTextField.prefHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());
            //HBox.setHgrow(inputTextField, Priority.ALWAYS);
            inputTextField.setBackground(null);

            tags.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> change) -> {
                while (change.next()) {
                    if (change.wasPermutated()) {
                        ArrayList<Node> newSublist = new ArrayList<>(change.getTo() - change.getFrom());
                        
                        for (int i = change.getFrom(), end = change.getTo(); i < end; i++) {
                            newSublist.add(null);
                        }
                        
                        for (int i = change.getFrom(), end = change.getTo(); i < end; i++) {
                            newSublist.set(change.getPermutation(i), getChildren().get(i));
                        }
                        
                        getChildren().subList(change.getFrom(), change.getTo()).clear();
                        getChildren().addAll(change.getFrom(), newSublist);
                    } else {
                        if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                            getChildren().subList(change.getFrom(), change.getFrom() + change.getRemovedSize()).clear();
                        }
                        
                        if (change.wasAdded()) {
                            getChildren().addAll(change.getFrom(), change.getAddedSubList().stream().map(Tag::new).collect(
                                    Collectors.toList()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            
            getChildren().add(inputTextField);
        }

        private TextFlow buildTextFlow(String text, String filter) {
            int filterIndex = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase());
            Text textBefore = new Text(text.substring(0, filterIndex));
            Text textAfter = new Text(text.substring(filterIndex + filter.length()));
            Text textFilter = new Text(text.substring(filterIndex, filterIndex + filter.length()));
            
            textFilter.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
            textFilter.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
            
            return new TextFlow(textBefore, textFilter, textAfter);
        }

        private void setListner() {
            inputTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    entriesPopup.hide();
                } else {
                    List<String> filteredEntries = suggestions
                            .stream()
                            .filter(e -> e.toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                    if (!filteredEntries.isEmpty()) {
                        populatePopup(filteredEntries, newValue);
                        
                        if (!entriesPopup.isShowing()) {
                            entriesPopup.show(this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        entriesPopup.hide();
                    }
                }
            });

            focusedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> entriesPopup.hide());
        }

        private void populatePopup(List<String> searchResult, String searchRequest) {
            List<CustomMenuItem> menuItems = new LinkedList<>();
            
            searchResult.stream()
                    .limit(MAX_ENTRIES)
                    .forEach(result -> {
                        TextFlow textFlow = buildTextFlow(result, searchRequest);
                        textFlow.prefWidthProperty().bind(AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox.this.widthProperty());
                        CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(textFlow, true);
                        
                        menuItems.add(item);

                        item.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                            if (result.endsWith("=")) {
                                //Dont close it yet.. keep typing
                                inputTextField.setText(result);
                                inputTextField.requestFocus();
                                inputTextField.end();
                            } else {
                                //It has values on both sides of the =
                                //so lets add it to the tag list
                                tags.add(result);
                                suggestions.remove(result);
                                inputTextField.clear();
                                entriesPopup.hide();
                            }
                        });
                    });

            entriesPopup.getItems().clear();
            entriesPopup.getItems().addAll(menuItems);
        }

        public final ObservableList<String> getTags() {
            return tags;
        }

        public final ObservableSet<String> getSuggestions() {
            return suggestions;
        }
        
        public final void setTextColor(Color c) {
            txtColor = c;
        }

        public final void setSuggestions(ObservableSet<String> suggestions) {
            this.suggestions.clear();
            this.suggestions.addAll(suggestions);
        }

        private class Tag extends FlowPane {
            Tag(String tag) {
                Button removeButton = new Button();
                Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("delete.png").toExternalForm());
                ImageView view = new ImageView(img);
                
                view.setFitHeight(16);
                view.setPreserveRatio(true);
                
                getStyleClass().add("tag");
                
                removeButton.setBackground(null);
                removeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                    tags.remove(tag);
                    suggestions.add(tag);
                    inputTextField.requestFocus();
                });

                Text text = new Text(tag);
                
                text.setFill(txtColor);
                text.setFont(Font.font(text.getFont().getFamily(), FontWeight.BOLD, text.getFont().getSize()));

                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                //setSpacing(2);
                setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5));

                removeButton.setGraphic(view);
                
                getChildren().addAll(text, removeButton);
            }
        }
    }
}

UPDATE 2
Here is the CSS (application.css):
/* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */
.tag-bar {
    -fx-border-color: #dbdae7;
    -fx-spacing: 1;
    -fx-padding: 1;
    -fx-max-height: 30;
}

.tag-bar .tag {
    -fx-border-color: b7b5cf;
    -fx-background-color: #dbdae7;
    -fx-border-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
}

.tag-bar .tag {
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
}

.tag-bar #tagText {
    -fx-text-fill: orange;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

And the png (delete.png):


Create and post a [mre].

@James_D do you not see my code I posted?

Yes. There is way more code than is necessary to describe and reproduce the problem. Write a new app from scratch which demonstrates the problem and does nothing else. This should have been part of your troubleshooting efforts before posting here anyway.

Additionally, an HBox will not wrap (see the documentation); a FlowPane is the way to do this. But we cannot help with your implementation using a FlowPane if we don't know what's wrong ("makes it look all weird" is not a problem description) and can't see the code where you tried using a FlowPane.

@James_D Updated my OP with the output of using the FlowPane.

A tag could probably just be a Label with text and a graphic, probably with the graphic being a Button. Then style the label and button to get the desired look. No need to create a subclass. Finally, put the labels in a FlowPane. Since labels are configured to not grow beyond their preferred size by default, you shouldn't run into the problem where they grow to fill the space.

Some of the problems with the height of some nodes are also caused by inputTextField.prefHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty()). It's not really clear what the intention of this line is, and in general I don't recommend binding layout size properties to dimension properties of an ancestor node, as weird things can happen. But again, I don't understand what this line of code is supposed to be doing anyway.

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37498869/2423906

TLDR: Make the tag container a FlowPane and each individual tag a  Label.

An HBox doesn't wrap: from the documentation:

HBox lays out its children in a single horizontal row

(my emphasis).
To wrap, you need a FlowPane instead of the HBox.
There is no need to represent each individual tag with a FlowPane, however: if you do so the layout for the tag will be incorrect (for example, the preferred width of a flow pane will default to 400 in this case; again see the documentation).
In fact, as pointed out in the comments, you can fairly easily just represent each tag with just a Label, which will avoid the unnecessary subclassing. (Generally, your UI code should follow all the usual good coding practices, such as "prefer aggregation to inheritance".) Using managed nodes, such as Control and Region and their subclasses, will generally work better for layout than using unmanaged nodes such as Shape and its subclasses (including Text).
Here is a pared-down version of what I think you are trying to do, with most of the functionality that is not related to layout problems, along with any dependence on external resources, removed. I provided just a little styling of the tags but this can obviously be improved.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TagDemo extends Application {

    private ObservableList<String> tags;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        tags = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        FlowPane tagPane = new FlowPane();
        tagPane.setHgap(5);
        tagPane.setVgap(5);
        tags.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> change) -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    int from = change.getFrom();
                    int to = change.getTo();
                    tagPane.getChildren().subList(from, to + 1).clear();
                }
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    tagPane.getChildren().addAll(
                            change.getFrom(),
                            change.getAddedSubList().stream().map(this::createTag).toList()
                    );
                }
            }
        });
        TextField tagField = new TextField();
        tagField.setPromptText("New Tag");
        tagField.setOnAction(_ -> {
            if (! tagField.getText().isBlank()) {
                tags.add(tagField.getText());
                tagField.clear();
            }
        });
        tagPane.getChildren().add(tagField);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tagPane);
        root.setTop(new Label("Tags:"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Node createTag(String tagName) {
        Label label = new Label(tagName);
        Button delete = new Button("X");
        delete.setOnAction(_ -> tags.remove(tagName));
        label.setGraphic(delete);
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        label.setGraphicTextGap(1);
        label.setStyle("-fx-color: lightsteelblue; -fx-background-color: lightsteelblue;");
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}



So the pre-suggestions and the ability to edit the text before officially making it a tag had to be taken out?

@StealthRT Not sure I understand your comment exactly, but the pre-suggestions (if I understand what those are) and editing the text seem to be completely irrelevant to the question you are asking here, so I omitted them in order to make the answer more understandable to other users. Bear in mind we cannot run the code you posted, because it is incomplete.

Not sure why it wouldn't run for you? I did add the CSS and the image if that was what you were referring to as it not being able to be ran because it was missing those.

@StealthRT Yes, that makes it complete ("reproducible"), and the "pre-suggestions" do more or less what I thought they do. I still don't understand what they have to do with your actual question though (which is about layout), so I don't know why you would include them in the question or think it is a good idea to include them in the answer.

It seems that all that was needed to do was the following:
Removing the line:
inputTextField.prefHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());

Editing the line:
public class AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox extends VBox {

to
public class AutocompleteMultiSelectionBox extends FlowPane {



Can you explain what the removed line of code was doing, and how you solved whatever problem it was intended to solve without it?

What was happening with theinputTextField.prefHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty()) is the tags (InputFields) had their preferred height following the overall container itself.

Yes, I understand what the code means; I just don't know why you were trying to do that. Especially as you have padding in there, which is going to make the container want to be a little taller than the text field. Presumably you put that code in there to solve some other problem. How are you solving that problem (whatever it is) without that code?
